# Custom Polymer component returning error: unexpected token . base.js:164

Tags: ajax, polymer

I'm prototyping a Polymer-based front end for a clean RESTful services layer. I think I've got the component-level AJAX working, but it's not painting to the Shadow DOM...instead, I'm getting an error in Chrome: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token . from base.js:164 (root.appendChild(dom)).

My code:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">

<polymer-element name="feed-posts">
    <template>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/styles.css">

        <core-ajax id="stream" url="https://api.myhost.com/1/streams" handleAs="json" params=" {{ streamparams }}" auto on-core-response="{{ feedLoaded }}"></core-ajax>

        <template repeat="{{f in feed }}">
            <div class="tile">
                <div class="heroTop">
                    <div class="headline">Post ID is {{ f }}</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </template>

        <script>
            Polymer('#stream', {
                accesstoken: document.querySelector('app-globals').accesstoken,
                userid: document.querySelector('app-globals').userid,
                streamparams: { "access_token": this.accesstoken, "user_id": this.userid }
            });
        </script>


    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer('newsfeed-posts', {
        created: function(){
            this.feed = [];
        },

        feedLoaded: function(){
            this.feed = this.$.stream.response['post_ids'];
        }
    });


    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Is this a bug with polymer, or (infinitely more likely) user error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
Polymer('#stream', {
    this.accesstoken = document.querySelector('app-globals').accesstoken;
    this.userid = document.querySelector('app-globals').userid;
    this.streamparams = {
        "access_token": this.accesstoken,
        "user_id": this.userid
    };
});
```

should at least look like this:

```
Polymer('#stream', {
    accesstoken: document.querySelector('app-globals').accesstoken,
    userid: document.querySelector('app-globals').userid,
    streamparams: {
        "access_token": this.accesstoken,
        "user_id": this.userid
    },
});
```

Use a code linter and you will find those errors (Syntax Errors) before you even run your code.

But nevertheless there are more errors in your code. Go ahead and read the awesome [polymer docs](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/creatingelements.html).

Comment: Thanks, Oliver - good catch. Error persists, but syntax matters. Edited.

Comment: I take that back - that did solve the error. Thanks!

Comment: `Polymer('#stream', {` doesn't make any sense. The `Polymer()` function registers a custom element that has a matching `polymer-element`. I'm not sure what that code is supposed to be doing, it looks like stuff you mostly want in your `newsfeed-posts` prototype.